# MS Access: Linked Tables - how to get the connection string when linked table manager is not installed

Tags: ms-access

I'm looking after a database while its author is on holiday. The server it's running on has no linked table manager, and the db is giving me an error - "ODBC --connnection to 'XYZ' failed." when I try to Domd.OpenQuery a query that's depending on a linked table.

I get the same message when I try to open said linked table. How do I find out where it's pointing to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the table in design mode, accept the warning with "Yes", look into the "Properties" window of the table (not the one of the column -- in Access 2007, the table properties window is docked on the right-hand side of the window; in earlier versions there's a button in the tool bar, if I remember correctly). The "Description" field contains the ODBC string for the table.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the connect property. in the immediate window:

```
?CurrentDb.TableDefs("LinkedTableName").Connect
```

The property is updatable.

Answer (score 1):

[Relink Access tables from code](http://www.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0009.htm)